# SSRS: PDF export inserts blank pages

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that for some unknown reason wants to insert blank pages.  I have set the consumecontainerwhitespace property to false (which eliminated some blank pages).  I've made sure that the height of the body plus the margins plus the header/footer heights are less than 8 inches (the report is 6.4 inches tall taking all that into account).  I've made sure that the width is less than 11.5 inches.  Despite all this, SSRS insists on making every odd page blank.  I am completely out of ideas to try.

Can anyone out there suggest any other tweaks I may have overlooked?

EDIT: Added requested screenshot:
[image]

Design view screenshot
[image]

Properties close up:

[image]

Comment: I've run into this problem several times and it's almost always because something is slightly off the page.  Try printing in landscape or condensing everything more.

Comment: I've looked and nothing is off the page (all the boxes are within the bounds of the report body).  All my widths are less than 11 inches.  I am printing in landscape mode.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a screenshot of the report?

Comment: The report margins are 0.5 inches all around.

Comment: A screenshot of the report in design mode with the ruler visible would be helpful.

Comment: Requested screenshots added.

Comment: I don't see the ruler in the design screenshot. We need to see the width of the widest element on the report. Your margins appear to be 1 inch, not 0.5 inches.

Comment: Dang, that's because I screenshotted the wrong report for the properties close up.  The margins are actually half an inch all around.

Comment: Screenshots have been corrected.

Comment: Looks good, thanks! There's got to be an element on there somewhere that is over the 10 inch width. Check the [report body size using the properties window](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MCwxU.png) if you haven't already. Even a 10.1 inch width would cause the blank page to be inserted.

Comment: I found it and everything works now.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the body was 10.1 inches.  This was corrected and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the page orientation to Landscape mode?

In Visual Studio, click the REPORT menu, then Report Properties.

Otherwise, I'd look at paging settings, whether your formatting might possibly be pushing something just a tiny bit off screen, etc.